# Notational clarifications for an exercise to show that $f$ is onto iff $2^{f}$ is one-to-one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The following question, is taken from Arbib and Manes’ *Arrows, structures and functors* text:

> Let $2^{A}$ define the power set of all subsets of $A$. Given $f \colon A\rightarrow B$ define $2^{f} \colon 2^{B}\rightarrow 2^{A}$ by  $2^{f}(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A \mid f(a)\in B\}.$ Prove that $f$ is onto iff $2^{f}$ is one-to-one.

I am not sure how to interpret the notation: $2^{f}(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A \mid f(a)\in B\}$.

Usually the power set of $A$ is denoted by $P(A)=\{X \mid X\subset A\}$, but for the power set of all subsets of $A$, does $2^{A}$ then mean $P(P(A))=\{W \mid W\subset P(A)\}$?

Also for $2^{f}(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A \mid f(a)\in B\}$, what does the set $S$ has to do with $f$’s domain and codomain? I would expect to see $f^{-1}(B)$ instead of $f^{-1}(S)$, unless $S\subset B$. Can someone please clarify this question’s notation to me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The text is certainly wrong because $\{a\in A|f(a)\in B\}$ is equal to $A$, meaning $2^f$ is a constant function and thus never one-to-one...

Comment: @donaastor can I ask what the correct form of the question is supposed to be.  Also, I thought if a function $f$ is a split monomorphism, then it is monic, according to here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Split_Monomorphism_is_Monic

Comment: I am sorry, I just have no idea what the text would try to say. I just see that something is missing there. I hope you will demystify it.

Comment: @donaastor okk.  thank you.

Comment: and btw, $2^A$ is another common notation for the power set of $A$, $P(A)$ and $2^A$ should be the same thing

Comment: @donaastor ah kk.  Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Maybe $2^f:2^B\rightarrow2^A:S\mapsto f^{-1}(S)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct statement should be

> Let $2^X$ be the power set of the set $X$, the set of all subsets of $X$. Given $f:A\rightarrow B$ define $2^f:2^B\rightarrow2^A$ by $2^f(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A|f(a)\in S\}$. Prove that $f$ is onto iff $2^f$ is one-to-one.

This is now well defined and true and your version is certainly wrong for 2 reasons. First, $\{a\in A|f(a)\in B\}=A$, which means that $2^f$ is constant and never one-to-one whenever $A\neq\emptyset$. There certainly exist non-empty onto functions. Secondly, if we tried to fix the definition of $2^f$ with $2^f(S)=f(S)$, then $2^f$ being one-to-one would imply that $f$ is one-to-one. So that way of fixing it is wrong.

Proof of my fixed version:

> We will prove 2 parts: (1) $f$ is not onto $\Rightarrow$ $2^f$ is not one-to-one; and (2) $f$ is onto $\Rightarrow$ $2^f$ is one-to-one. (1): There exists $b\in B$ such that there is no $a\in A$ for which $f(a)=b$. Then $2^f(\emptyset)=2^f(\{b\})$ so $2^f$ isn't one-to-one. (2): Let $X$ and $Y$ be 2 different subsets of $B$ and without loss of generality let's assume that $X\setminus Y\neq\emptyset$. Take some $x\in X\setminus Y$. There is some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=x$. Then $2^f(X)=f^{-1}(X)\supseteq f^{-1}(\{x\})\ni a$ but $2^f(Y)=f^{-1}(Y)\not\ni a$, because otherwise it would mean $f(a)\in Y$, i.e. $x\in Y$ which is not. This means that $2^f(X)$ and $2^f(Y)$ aren't equal, meaning $2^f$ is one-to-one.

Comment: can I ask what the relationship of  $S$ to $B$ is?  i am thinking you have $S\subset B$ in mind.  Sorry I am still not clear on that point.

Comment: @Seth Yes, that's right, in definition I stated that the domain of $2^f$ is $2^B$, so $S$ must be a subset of $B$.

Comment: Are you familiar with function defining notations? Whenever you write $f(x)$ you are assuming that $x$ is in the domain of $f$. The right arrow symbol $\rightarrow$ defines the domain and codomain, so the statement $f:X\rightarrow Y$ means that $f$ is a function and $X$ and $Y$ are its domain and codomain. The arrow $\mapsto$ is pronounced "maps to" and the statement $x\mapsto y$ means $x$ maps to $y$ (under some mapping ie function which is not yet stated in the context), so the statement $f:x\mapsto y$ means $f$ maps $x$ to $y$. Here we did define the function for the context and...

Comment: ...and it is assumed, of course, that $x$ is in $f$'s domain and that $y$ is in $f$'s codomain. So the full statement $f:X\rightarrow Y:x\mapsto y$ means $f$ is a function whose domain is $X$ and codomain is $Y$ and it maps arbitrary point $x$ from $X$ to $y$ from $Y$ (where $y$ would be "defined" using some formula which uses $x$ as a variable among other variables).

Comment: my apologies for the late reply.  When I first saw $2^{f}(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A|f(a)\in S\}$, I thought $S$ had to do with some other sets unrelated to $A$ or $B$.  I am learning category theory on my own, so if this was a homework assignment, I am not sure if I can get away with not specifying $S\subset B$ or just write $2^{f}(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A|f(a)\in S\subset B\}.$  I am still at the undergrad level and I am not sure how much terseness or carelessness I can get away with in terms of preciseness.  Also...

Comment: ..thank you for your clear write up and taking the time to clarify the question for me.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Seth No problem. Happy to help! Unfortunately, mathematicians like to be very compact and write as little as possible... I am an undergraduate as well! I see this lack of precission a lot, sadly... Like, in your example the line "defined by $2^f(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A|f(a)\in S\}$" has two signs $=$ with 2 completely different meanings. The first sign is the defining equal, that part introduces something new to the reader (and should have been $:=$ instead of $=$, the colon symbol is generally used to indicate definition) and the second is just a true statement, meant to clarify $f^{-1}(S)$...

Comment: ... and the whole sentence "$2^f:2^B\rightarrow 2^A$ defined by $2^f(S)=$..." means $2^f$ is a function with these domain and codomain which satisfies $2^f(S)=...$ which obviously defines in uniquely. In similar fashion the sentence $2^f:2^B\rightarrow 2^A:S\mapsto$... says the exact same thing; $2^f$ is a function with these domain and codomain which *maps* $S$ to ...

Comment: actually there are a few other things I want to ask you, when you write "$2^f(\emptyset)=2^f(\{b\})$ so $2^f$ isn't one-to-one.", how does $2^f(\emptyset)=2^f(\{b\})$ make $2^f$ not one to one.   Also, $2^f(S)$ as a function, the arguments in that function are $S$, like $x$ are the argument for the function $f(x)$, is that correct?  Lastly how did you do the "reveal spoiler" thingie in your post.

Comment: @Seth haha the reveal spoiler thingie is just how paragraphs which begin with ">!" are rendered; normal quotation should begin with only ">". You learn many things when you start using linux and visit some old fashioned forums :D Function is one to one (or _injective_) if $x\neq y\Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$ (by definition). So in this case we have $2^f(\emptyset)=2^f(\{b\})=\emptyset$, but $\emptyset\neq\{b\}$ implies the opposite, thus contradiction. You are correct that $S$ is the argument, $2^f$ is just an expression as any other, including $f$, if we defined it to be a function then it's...

Comment: ... just a fuhnction. So you write $2^f$ and then it's argument in the brackets, just like you would do with $f$ alone. Or did I understand your "one-to-one" wrongly? I assumed it means injective becuase it makes a true statement, perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: you are explanations are perfect.  Thank you so much for taking the time out to respond to my questions.

Comment: @Seth No problem. I am motivated by the wish to acquire skills of locating other people's holes in understanding and filling them. I hope I did somewhat acceptably... For example I am now not sure if you understand well that $S$ is a single argument; that $2^f$ maps $S$ as a whole, it doesn't do anything with elements of $S$ individually and then extend the result to the map of the whole $S$. But I guess it is less likely that you misunderstood that anyway.

Comment: thank you again.  