# solution check request for showing that $(2^m, 2^e)$ is an epi-mono factorization of $2^f$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, category-theory

The following question, is taken from Arbib and Manes’ *Arrows, structures and functors* text:

**Question:** Prove that if $(e,m)$ is an epi-mono factorization of $f$ then $(2^m, 2^e)$ is an epi-mono factorization of $2^f$.

Proof:  Since $e$ is a surjective map, then by the quoted exercise below, the inverse image map $2^e$ is injective. We only need to show that the inverse image map $2^m$ is surjective.  Let the direct image map $m$ be defined as $2^{[m]}:P(C)\rightarrow P(B),$ $S\in P(C)$, and $Y=2^{[m]}(S)$  Since $m$ is injective then $2^{m}(Y)=2^{m}(2^{[m]}(S))=S$. Hence a set $Y$ can always be found for every $S\in P(C)$, therefore the map $2^{m}$ is a surjection.

The relevant definition, proposition and exercises which the above question is based on are as follows:

> **Definition:**  We say that the pair $(e, m)$ epi-mono factorization of the map $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ if $e$ is an epimorphism and $m$ is a monomorphism such that $f = m \circ e$.
> [image]
>
> **Proposition:**  Epi-mono factorizations are unique up to isomorphism in the sense that if $(e', m')$ is an epi-mono factorization
>
> [image]
>
> of a given map $f \colon A \rightarrow B$, then there is an isomorphism $\phi$ such that the above diagram commutes.
>
> Exercise: Let $2^{A}$ denote the power set of all subsets of $A$.  Given $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ define $2^{f} \colon 2^{B} \rightarrow 2^{A}$ by $2^{f}(S) = f^{-1}(S) = \{a \in A \mid f(a) \in S \subset B\}$. Prove that $f$ is onto iff $2^{f}$ is one-to-one.

I have asked in different posts concerning issues of notation being confusing  for the question concerned in this post and the quoted exercise, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594517/correct-wording-of-an-exercise-about-showing-that-a-map-is-an-epic-mono-factoriz) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4593779/notational-clarifications-for-an-exercise-to-show-that-f-is-onto-iff-2f-i).

Can someone go over my solution and see if I have done it correctly.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it is worth adding links to your previous questions.

Comment: @Trebor I did as you suggested it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken from the beginning.

$m$ is given, and is not from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$ but from some set $C$ (not necessarily $f(A)$) to $B.$

And to prove that $2^m$ is surjective, you must not start from an $X\in P(A)$ but from an $X\in P(C)$ (and find some $S\in P(B)$ such that $m^{-1}(S)=X$).

However, your central sentence is the right argument: "[Let] $S=m(X).$  Since $m$ is injective then $m^{-1}(S)=m^{-1}(m(X))=X$".

Comment: I fixed my post. I am not sure if I got all the notations correct.

Comment: Now it is correct, up to the fact that (as mentionned in my answer) the domain of $m$ is not supposed to be $f(A).$ And there should be no $Y$ in your last sentence. The surjection is not the set $2^m(Y)$ but the map $2^m.$

Comment: in the commutative diagram image, the domain of $m$ is $f(A)$, so if not $f(A)$, what should it be instead?  There is a reason why I think the notation of $2^m$ and $2^m()$ is confusing for me still.

Comment: The commutative diagram is not consistent with the definition. It is only used to illustrate a proof of *existence* of an epi-mono factorization of $f.$ But look at the proposition below the definition.

Comment: Also, Kevin Arlin in the other post told me that $C=f(A)$.  Sorry I am confused now.

Comment: I thought the $C'$ in the proposition are only used for proving the theorem, and I was supposed to resort back to the commutative diagram if I have to straight up use the definition.  I am not trying to argue with you, I am honestly telling you this is what I thought what the authors intended.

Comment: No worry, I am absolutely convinced of your sincere desire not to argue but to be sure to understand. The $C'$ in the 2nd diagram is the intermediate set of an *arbitrary* epi-mono factorization of $f,$ and the (omitted) proof of the proposition shows that such a factorization is *isomorphic* to the "canonical" one (the one with $f(A)$), isomorphic in the sense of the diagram. In your exercise, you start from an arbitrary factorization $(e,m)$ which (despite its name) is not supposed to be the canonical one.

Comment: okay, no worries. Thank you again for checking over my solutions.

Comment: I think that if @KevinArlin agreed to your question whether his $C$ was $f(A),$ it is uniquely to concentrate on more fundamental misunderstandings. He knew it was only "nearly true" (true up to the isomorphism of the proposition above) but did not want to discuss this nuance.

Comment: I asked someone about this question and the person explained to me why it should just be $C$.  Also, I was confused over why Kevin said the map $2^f(S)$ is a set.  He was commenting on my earlier comment which I misunderstood him to be commenting on the question from the post.  If I want to write $2^f$ in function notation, then it should be written as $2^f:S\mapsto f^{-1}(S)$.

Comment: I agree with your last formula (or to be more complete: $2^f:2^B\to2^A,\;S\mapsto f^{-1}(S)$). Not with your "the map $2^f(S)$". It *is* a set (for any subset $S$ of $B$). The map is $2^f$ *naked* (without that $S$).